# Cannot create a histogram data by reading an Image file

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram data by reading an Image file:

```
>> img = imread('Flowers.jpg');
>> g = img(:,:,2);
>> bins = 0:1:255;
>> H = hist(g(:), bins);
?? Error using ==> full
Function 'full' is not defined for values of class 'uint8'.

Error in ==> C:\MATLAB\toolbox\matlab\datafun\hist.m
On line 66  ==>     xx = full(real(xx)); y = full(real(y)); % For compatibility
>> version

ans =

6.5.0.180913a (R13)

>>
```

I am not sure why I am receiving this error?

Comment: replace second line to `g = double(img(:,:,2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing toolbox, I recommend you use `imhist` instead.  This will handle `uint8` images natively, without having to do any conversion, and works on binary and greyscale images.

Similarly to `hist`, you can either call it without outputs to just get the image directly, or get the outputs and plot the result yourself.  Unlike `hist`, you can only give it a number of bins (for greyscale, this defaults to 256), not a vector.

```
img = imread('Flowers.jpg');
g = img(:,:,2);
[counts, x] = imhist(g);
stem(x,counts); % or bar, or whatever you prefer
```

The output `x` here will be the same as your `bins`.